# How to find if a coordinate is within a polygon in mongoose for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have tried many different attempts but have failed. Currently, my query doesn't fail but it doesn't provide me any results. I am using Mongoose v 3.8.9 which uses Mongodb v 1.4. 
I think my coordinates are indexed properly, since it works for quering using .geoNear(). However, geoNear() only allows for a single coordinate and hence I can't specifty g

Here is a sample of it that runs but doesn't return any result. I have even changed one of the documents to contain the point exactly to one of the four points specified in geoJSONpolygon.

```
 var geoJSONpolygon = { type: 'Polygon',coordinates:[[43.6582231,-79.3988945],[43.6583683,-79.3980648],[43.6583143,-79.3979845],[43.6584212,-79.3975422]] }

  newLocation.find({}).where('pos').within().geometry(geoJSONpolygon).lean().exec(function(err,doc){
    console.log(doc);
    res.send(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I use, might help you.

```
   Position.find(
        { geo :
                     { $geoWithin : { $box :
                                      [ [ box[0] , box[1] ] ,
                                        [ box[2] , box[3] ] ] } }

    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) return err;

        console.log(response)

    });
```

You can also set to debug and check the result:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true)
```

Comment: it's still not working, which version of mongoose are you using ?

Comment: YESSS! it works :D. Thanks ! I didn't even know about $box, I was using $polygon this whole time.